# Use ShGetFolderPath in Delphi, which unit should I include?

Tags: shell, delphi, winapi

I try to use ShGetFolderPath in Delphi XE3. Since it is an Windows API, I search the Delphi source codes and find both Winapi.ShFolder.pas and WinApi.Shlobj.pas have its definition. I try to include ShFolder or ShlObj, both are OK. So which unit should I include for using ShGetFolderPath? Or can I just use any?

Comment: You could use either. Both contains `ShGetFolderPath` function declaration.

Comment: Module `Shlobj` is most probably supposed to be import of `shlobj.h` header. The function is defined in `shlobj_core.h` header, but `Shlobj` is still closer to Windows SDK. `ShFolder` is not the name of any Windows SDK header. So I would be for `Shlobj`.

Comment: @TLama "*`ShFolder` is not the name of any Windows SDK header*" - `ShFolder.h` used to be in the SDK, but it was deprecated around Windows 2000 and its content was moved to `shlobj.h`.

Comment: @Remy, how I miss Windows 2000 days :) Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 2):

[`SHGetFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetfolderpatha) is deprecated and is supported only for backward compatibility.

For new system and new application you can use [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) instead.

About which header to include you can refer to document of that API and check the requirements part.

[image]